# How to refresh a Map in java

Tags: java, dictionary, refresh

i have a problem. i need to refresh positions on a GPS that shows truck and their position. Here is the code for displaying the truck:

```
private static void addMarkerTruck(String name, double x, double y,
            int mVitesse)
    {

        BitmapDescriptor icon;
        double mLatitude =x;
        double mLongitude = y;
        Marker currentMarker = getMarker(name);
        if ( getMarker(name) != null)
        {
            currentMarker.setPosition(new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude));
        }
        else
        {
            if (mVitesse <= 0)
            {
                icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.truck_orange);
            } else if (mVitesse > 5 && mVitesse < 90)
            {
                icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.truck_blue);
            } else
            {
                icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.truck_black);
            }

            Marker mark = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(name)
                    .position(new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude))
                    .snippet(String.valueOf("Vitesse: " + mVitesse + " km/h ")).icon(icon));

                    vehicles.put(name, mark);
        }
            //mark.setPosition(latlng);
}
```

And here is the refresh that doesn't work properly.

```
public static void refreshMarkersPosition()
    {
        mMap.clear();
        displayAllCar();
        if (FragmentMainMenu.booleanShowPoi == 1)
        {
            displayAllPoi();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why is everything static?

Comment: i didn't code that. i'm working on a existing code. My boss coded it

Comment: It's look like nMap is custom class. Ask someone who created it.

Comment: Ok it's not in static anymor, it made a mistake

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't work properly`? I.e. what do you expect? What kind of unexpected result or behavior do you have? You have to provide more contextual information about your issue if you want people (to be able) to help you. See [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for instance.

Comment: My problem was that when the marker refreshed, they all disapeared. But it's ok i fixed it. I just had to erase mMap.clear(). Sorry for the inconvenient, and i'll learn to ask for next time. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The mMap.clear method is throwing away all the data you had previously collected, not just the GPS locations (i.e. the Marker). In particular, it is throwing away the name that you are using as the map key.